# How to avoid to recompile project every time I made a change to a view in .NET Core project?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2022

I am new to .NET Core 6 project using Razor views. One problem I am having now is that, every time I make a minimal change to a page, I need to recompile so that I can see the change in the browser.

I am using IIS Express as the server. That way, I can develop while the server is still running, but there is a thing left to solve, and it is to avoid to recompile the project when I change a view.

I realized if I make a change to a view, change is not seen until I recompile the project.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is [Hot Reload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/hot-reload?view=vs-2022#supported-aspnet-core-scenarios):

> ### Supported ASP.NET Core Scenarios
>
> For ASP.NET Core developers who are targeting .NET 6, there are additional capabilities not available for lower versions of .NET. These capabilities include:
>
> - CSHTML: Editing a Razor CSHTML file supports many types of edits.
> - Browser Refresh: Editing a razor file automatically refreshes the changes in your web browser when debugging. This feature was
>   previously only available when starting the app without the debugger.
> - CSS Hot Reload: You can change CSS files while the app is running, and changes are applied immediately to the running app as you type.
> - No Debugger: You get Hot Reload support when using Visual Studio to start your web app without the debugger (CTRL-F5).

You can enable Hot Reload by going to Tools → Options → Debugging → .NET / C++ Hot Reload:

[image: menu showing how to navigate to hot reload options]